Is there a fix/mod to accelerate drawing waveforms in LTspice
LTspice is very slow to draw the waveform window. This can be so extreme, that the software spends the entire time trying to rescale/redraw the graphs, especially for busy waveforms for things such as switching converters. As a result it can indeed become unresponsive or even crash.
Is there a fix for that, maybe some GPU acceleration or something?
(I am not speaking about an issue of my PC, but about the general LTspice behavior. I am also not speaking about the simulation speed, but the drawing speed, even post-simulation.)

Are you using LTspice 24? I think they added some UI improvements in this version.

@SteKulov I think I have version 14 or something like that?! I thought it made no difference because I've not really perceived any change in LTspice through the versions every since I started using it. But I can give it a try

It came out earlier this year. It’s worth trying out to see if it draws faster. There’s also QSPICE which was written by the same author (Mike Engelhardt), so the underlying SPICE engines are similar but uses a brand new UI. Could be worth giving that a shot too and seeing if it draws any faster.

@SteKulov Qspice was the keyword. It is. SO. MUCH. FASTER. Not just the drawing but the sims too. I wish I hadn't lost hours of my live sitting in front of LTspice sims ;) Now I will have to spend a few hours rewriting some models and components. But only once :) Mike leaving LTspice should have been a wake-up call but somehow complacency made me ignore it. And I suffered for this :) If you could write a short answer, I can accept that.

I can, but I’m curious to know if you also tried LTspice 24. It’s quite different than LTspice 17.

@SteKulov No I haven't tried 24. But I am currently pretty happy also with the other improvements of Qspice such as better models for Class II caps, VDMOS, JFET... So I am not planning to try LT 24 at this point.

It sounds like you are using LTspice 17.x, which is quite an old version and now deprecated.  There are many GUI improvements in the latest version of LTspice which at the time of this writing is 24.0.12.
I created a simple circuit to run comparison experiments across different software/versions.  All the experiments were performed on the same computer on the same operating system (Windows 10 2H22).
First, I ran the circuit on LTspice 17.0.36.  LTspice 17.x uses an old graphics/drawing engine, so not only is the simulation speed slower, but if you probe a node in a simulation with lots of time-points, it takes a VERY long time to draw the results.  For example, if you have "Marching Waveforms" enabled (which is ON by default) it will draw waveforms for any probed nodes while the simulation runs.  After the simulation is over, it will clear the screen and then re-draw the waveforms incurring an [annoying] extra time penalty. For the test circuit shown, I estimated an additional 10 seconds using my stopwatch for this extra time.  Anytime you probe a node after the simulations is over, you also have to wait for this additional time for the software to draw (or re-draw) the waveform.  Additionally, if you've ever tried ALT+TAB-ing to another program and back to LTspice, the waveform will have to re-draw itself (again, very slowly).  This appears to be a bottleneck in the graphics/drawing engine for LTspice 17.x.


Moving onto LTspice 24.0.12 with the same circuit, the simulation speed is a few seconds faster.  However, the GUI was updated to completely fix the drawing problem described above in LTspice 17.x.  Now after the simulation is over, any node that is probed appears instantly in the waveform viewer.  So there is no more drawing penalty, even when a marching waveform finishes.  This makes probing nodes with a high-time-point simulation much faster and FAR less frustrating.


So now that the graphics bottleneck is no longer there, the only thing slowing down the simulation is the actual underlying simulation engine.  Referencing the above experiments, LTspice 24.x is slightly faster than LTspice 17.x in raw simulation time, but not by much.  The original author of LTspice, Mike Engelhardt, recently released a new SPICE program for Qorvo, Inc. called QSPICE.  LTspice schematics aren't directly compatible with QSPICE, but almost all LTspice netlists should be since much of the underlying engine and its syntax are shared. Regardless, I redrew the circuit in the latest version of QSPICE (as of this writing) and made sure it used the same MOSFET model parameters as LTspice by declaring a custom .model statement imported from LTspice.  The QSPICE simulation runs 3.5x faster than LTspice 24.x!  That's a big improvement in speed.  I don't know how much this difference translates to other circuits, but it's worth noting.



Anyway, the main takeaway is if you want to boost the speed of LTspice it's worth it to always check the latest version since it's constantly being updated.  I'm personally still running 17.x because I'm still very used to it, but having the drawing penalty fixed is making me reconsider using 24.x.  If you want a further speed boost, then check out QSPICE.

It took me a while to finally get around to writing this, but I didn't want to make any assumptions and wanted to do it somewhat scientifically.

thanks. The answer addresses my issues with LTspice 17 exactly and investigates two solutions. at this point, LTspice versions are merely good to know for me.. I have moved on to Qspice which is not only faster, and has a lot of QoL improvements, it also has the soothing feeling of regular updates, several times per week.

The .raw data files become enormous when you are simulating very fast details in something that's taking place slowly, as in a switching converter where you are trying to simulate loop response.
Other than simplifying the circuit (probably at the expense of accuracy) or using a faster computer with loads of memory, I'm not sure there is a simple solution. Here are a couple things to try:

You can play with the compression settings (emphasis added)


LTspice compresses the raw data files as they are generated. A
compressed file can be 50 times smaller than the un-compressed one.
This is a lossy compression. This pane of the control panel allows you
to control how lossy the compression runs.


By using the .save directive you can have LTspice save only the data you intend to plot rather than all the data.


It is not about the size of the raw file. When I load presaved raw files or traces therein, then yes, it takes a considerable time to "load" them into memory from the disk. But they are always plotted from memory and this is much slower than memory bandwidth would allow. So it is a drawing/rendering issue, not a memory streaming issue. A faster CPU does help, but it's still too slow for comfort, when the same panel would likely be drawn in a fraction of a second using GPU acceleration:(

@tobalt Hmmm. Are you sure this is true? LTspice always generates a .raw file even if you don’t explicitly save it. I always thought the SPICE engine writes the .raw file and the UI then loads it into the Waveform Viewer. I don’t think there is a direct RAM link in between those two parts of the program. I could be wrong but that’s how I always understood it.

@SteKulov Yes I am absolutely sure it is only a drawing issue. When I make the waveform window tiny (so the traces span only a few pixels), it draws super fast but is not usable of course. Qspice is wonderfully similar but much faster and more modern though, so I will just use that.

@tobalt I think you misunderstood what I said. I wasn’t questioning if it was a drawing issue, but about how the .raw file interacts with the Waveform Viewer. It’s always reading from disk but it doesn’t matter because I think your issue is a graphics acceleration issue.

The slowing down when highly detailed (eg. huge) .raw files are plotted suggests to me that it's not just the graphics.
